# Longlist is not creating properly

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I want to populate longlist via WCF service. The compilation goes without errors, but the result of the executed program looks like three lines of this: `PhoneApp1.ServiceReference1.worker` instead of the name and other data I want to display. My service implementation is:

```
public IEnumerable<worker> GetStuffList()
    {
        List<worker> stuffList = new List<worker>();
        stuffList.Add(new worker("John", 23, true));
        stuffList.Add(new worker("Nick", 22, true));
        stuffList.Add(new worker("Gill", 23, false)); 
        return stuffList;
    }

    private List<Group<worker>> GetStuffEnumerable()
    {
        IEnumerable<worker> stuffList = GetStuffList();
        return GetItemGroups(stuffList, c => c.Age.ToString());
    }

    private static List<Group<T>> GetItemGroups<T>(IEnumerable<T> itemList, Func<T, string> getKeyFunc)
    {
        IEnumerable<Group<T>> groupList = from item in itemList
                                          group item by getKeyFunc(item) into g
                                          orderby g.Key
                                          select new Group<T>(g.Key, g);

        return groupList.ToList();
    }

    public class Group<T> : List<T>
    {
        public Group(string name, IEnumerable<T> items)
            : base(items)
        {
            this.Title = name;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to speficy an ItemTemplate for the LongListSelector. Without it, it is showing object.ToString().

Something like this:

```
<LonglistSelector ...>
    <LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>        
    </LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</LongListSelector/>
```